# Insert data into mysql database, gone from version 2.6 to 5.1 no longer works

Tags: php

I recently went from phpmyadmin 2.6 to 5.1, also installed wamp...I know long time coming.
I have a webform with simple variables and they are no longer inserting into my database

```
<form method="POST" action="record.php">

 td style="width: 472px">
    <input type=text name=travel size=40 style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF66; width: 270px;"></td>
    </tr>
```

and the insert php:::

```
<?
$travel=$_POST['travel'];
$db="xacall";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "sql", "sql");
//$link = mysql_connect("localhost",$_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db , $link) or die("Select Error: ".mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ircb (travel) VALUES ('$travel')")or die("Insert Error: ".mysql_error());

//write to file
$fp = fopen("IR_Call_Entries.txt", "a"); 
fwrite($fp, $_POST['travel'] . "\n" . 
close($fp);

?>
```

I submit , get no error message..but nothing is eneterd and nothing is written...is POST wrong..should I use GET ??? arrgh, confused, thanks
I have also echo'ed the variable and nothing shows

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, avoid `short_open_tags` reliance... start with `<?php`, not `<?` if you want to keep your code portable.

Comment: did you try echo the `$_POST` values?

Comment: `fwrite` line ends with a concat sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form as:

```
<form method="post" action="record.php">

<td style="width: 472px">
<input type="text" name="travel" size="40" style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF66; width: 270px;"></td>
</tr>
```

And also debug the post variable with: `print_r($_POST)`

```
    <?php #Please use full open tag.
    $travel=$_POST['travel'];
    $db='xacall';

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'sql', 'sql') or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
    mysql_select_db($db , $link) or die('Select Error: '.mysql_error());
    $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ircb (travel) VALUES ('$travel')")or die('Insert Error: '.mysql_error());


   print_r($_POST);

   #write to file
   $fp = fopen('IR_Call_Entries.txt', 'a'); 
   fwrite($fp, $_POST['travel'] . '\n' ; #you had a concat sign here? 
   close($fp);
   ?>
```

I have also used single quotes as much as possible.